# DS18B20, Pico W, 7 segment display and Micropython

Tags: ds18b20, micropython

My goal is to connect 2 DS18B20 sensors to a Pico W and display an indoor and outdoor temperature on a 4 digit seven segment display.

My problem is it crashes after 20 or so iterations.

Thanks for any help!

```
import machine
from machine import Pin
import onewire
import ds18x20
import time
import tm1637

ds_pin = machine.Pin(18)
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))
roms = ds_sensor.scan()
mydisplay = tm1637.TM1637(clk=Pin(16), dio=Pin(17))
sensor_temp = machine.ADC(4)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535)

 
while True:
    mydisplay.show("    ")
    reading = sensor_temp.read_u16() * conversion_factor 
    temperature = 27 - (reading - 0.706)/0.001721
    rz=round(temperature)
    ds_sensor.convert_temp()
    time.sleep_ms(750)
    mydisplay.show("    ")
    for rom in roms:
        print("Onewire Reading", ds_sensor.read_temp(rom))
# THIS DEFINES THIS AS AN INTEGER AND MAKES IT POSSIBLE TO SEND TO DISPLAY
        y = round(ds_sensor.read_temp(rom))
#END OF MATH AND DEFINITIONS, BEGIN CONSOLE PRINTS        
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    print("Interger Variable", y-3)
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    print("Onboard Sensor", (temperature))
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    print("-----------------")
    time.sleep(1)
#7 SEGMENT DISPLAY PRINTING BEGINS HERE
    mydisplay.brightness(1)
    #THIS IS THE ONBOARD TEMP SENSOR "INSIDE"
    mydisplay.show("    ")
    mydisplay.show("IN")
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    mydisplay.temperature(rz)
  #PAUSE BETWEEN IN AND OUT
    time.sleep(1)
    #THIS IS THE ONE WIRE "OUTSIDE"
    mydisplay.show("    ")
    mydisplay.show("OUT")
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    mydisplay.temperature(int(y-3))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If it's crashing after *n* iterations every single time, probably it's a memory issue. Add `import gc` and use `gc.mem_free()` to monitor the memory usage. Then, if it's a memory issue, use `gc.collect()` to clean the memory. More info in: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/gc.html